# Deconfigured locales for libc6 - help!

Tags: pi-3b+, ubuntu

So, I was trying to install firefox 81 on Ubuntu MATE 20.04. When I was trying to, it was saying libc6 needed 2.32 but I had 2.31 installed. So I decided to look up where 2.32 was an attempt to install the .deb package. I found it and tried to install it but it said something along the lines of that it wouldn't allow reconfiguration for locales libc6 2.31. I thought it would fix installing with `sudo dpkg -i --auto-deconfigure libc6_2.32-0ubuntu3_armhf.deb` and I think I screwed up.

[image]

Now these are broken and when I try to reinstall them, it wants to remove all these critical packages:

https://pastebin.com/uQgDLKpX

How can I fix this?? Can this be fixed? Or did I break my system? :(

EDIT: It is also showing this in terminal:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.32) but 2.32-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.32) but 2.32-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libc6 : Depends: libnss-nis but it is not installable
         Depends: libnss-nisplus but it is not installable
         Breaks: locales (< 2.32) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) but 2.32-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) but 2.32-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: did you try the suggestion in the last line of the terminal output you posted apt --fix-broken install

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Then it shows the same results above, whereas it want to install 3.1GB worth of core packages

Comment: If I were you I would back up any important settings/data and do a fresh install. Even if you appear to get it repaired, this type of error can lay hidden and come back to bite you in the future. And once back up and running make sure you set up a backup procedure and schedule.

Comment: I fixed it I think. I got the libc6 2.31 package and installed that, then did `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and it seems to fix it, no errors.